# fn:count give me 1's instead of the total count() number

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

Xquery 3.0

```
 for $x in doc("XMLexemplo.xml")/Calendario/Curso/UC/Unidade/Exames/Exame
    let $day := fn:day-from-date(xs:date($x/Dia))
    where $day>=20 and $day <=21
    return count($day)
```

The output is `1 1`but i expect `2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are asking for a count for each day, which is necessarily 1. What you want is to count the size of the whole result, so wrap the count around the whole FLWOR expression:

```
count(
  for $x in doc("XMLexemplo.xml")/Calendario/Curso/UC/Unidade/Exames/Exame
  let $day := fn:day-from-date(xs:date($x/Dia))
  where $day>=20 and $day <=21
  return $day
)
```